# how to create column with other dataframe as legend in python (groupby() alike)- pandas library

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

i want to use df2 as legend to my primary df ('main_df')

what "**code**" need to be ?

```
main_df = pd.DataFrame({'genre_NAME': ['comedy', 'action', 'horror'], 'genre_id': [nan, nan, nan]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'genre': ['comedy', 'horror'], 'id': [0, 1]})
 
#main_df is not relate to df2

some code
 
#result 

print(main_df)

*OUTPUT =* 'genre_NAME': ['comedy', 'action', 'horror'], 'genre_id': [0, nan,1]
```

Comment: `main_df['genre_id'] = main_df['genre_NAME'].map(dict(zip(df['genre'], df2['id'])))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access and change a specific value in a dataframe with `df.loc[]`. So in your case:

```
for _, line in df2.iterrows():
    main_df.loc[main_df.genre_NAME == line.genre, "genre_id"] = line.id
```